# How can I find which process are failing to connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have installed mysql 5.7.11 on Mac OS 10.13 High Sierra. The mysql server seemingly starts and stops without issues. I am having no noticeable issues connecting. I have been able to use phpmyadmin to setup a database for a local cms with no issues.

However, upon enabling general query logging in *my.cnf*:

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/my_general.log
```

*my_general.log* is being filled with connection error messages:

```
2018-01-15T11:33:56.933354Z   31 Connect    _mysql@localhost on  using Socket
2018-01-15T11:33:56.933387Z   31 Connect    Access denied for user '_mysql'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2018-01-15T11:33:58.934167Z   32 Connect    dylan@localhost on  using Socket
2018-01-15T11:33:58.934206Z   32 Connect    Access denied for user 'dylan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2018-01-15T11:34:10.933386Z   33 Connect    dylan@localhost on  using Socket
2018-01-15T11:34:10.933419Z   33 Connect    Access denied for user 'dylan'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

And randomly, `_netbios@localhost` is also denied access.

Which is consistent every time I start the server. It makes 30 failed attempts as `_mysql@localhost` and then switches to my user account. From what I can tell, it continues to fail indefinitely.

I don't have a *_mysql* user set up, there is a user *mysql.sys*. User *dylan* requires a password.

So, how can I tell what is trying to connect to mysql?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm seeing the same thing on Mac OS 10.13 with MySQL 5.7.19, except I don't see any messages about _netbios@localhost. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisBartley No, I didn't.  Deadlines. I ignored it for the week, and focused on the error log when I had to. I pushed code to Ubuntu staging server, no log spam. It seems to be a config issue, and wouldn't surprise me if it's leftover from some hidden OS X mysql installation from 3 OS upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just found this post a couple minutes ago, which says the log spam only happens as long as the System Preferences window is open: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/164820/143841  For me at least, I can confirm that the log messages do indeed go away after quitting System Preferences.